# Python multiple file input

Tags: python, command-line, file-handling

I'm working on a python program that prints the words that are in the last file entered from the command line. The words can't be in any of the preceding files. So for example if I input 2 files from the command line and

File 1 contains: "We are awesome" and File 2(the last file entered) contains: "We are really awesome"

My final list should only contain: "really"

Right now my code is set up to only look at the last file entered, how can I look at all of the preceding files and compare them in the context of what I am trying to do? Here is my code:

UPDATE

```
import re
import sys
def get_words(filename):
        test_file = open(filename).read()
        lower_split = test_file.lower()
        new_split = re.split("[^a-z']+", lower_split)
        really_new_split = sorted(set(new_split))
        return really_new_split
if __name__ == '__main__':

        bag = []
        for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
                bag.append(get_words(filename))

                unique_words = bag[-1].copy()
                for other in bag[:-1]:
                        unique_words -= other

                        for word in unique_words:
                                print(word)
```

Also:

```
>>> set([1,2,3])
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: You have almost all the bits there. I'm surprised you got stuck after mastering all the tricky bits. Anyway, try putting your code into a function with one argument, the filename and let it return the set you create with `set(new_split)` Then set up a loop over sys.argv (you may have to cut off one ore two elements on the left) and call your function with the names, collecting the return values in a list. You can find elements that are in your last set but not in a second set by simply taking the difference.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @PaulPanzer I'm unsure of how to create a loop with sys.argv (I'm very new to python).

Comment: Oh for Crist's sake! Look, I'm really happy to help, but if you can't even be bothered to be a bit careful when copying a few lines of code, you are just wasting my time. You really needn't be Bill Gates to see these are totally different from what I asked you to use. So please have a closer look at the code I posted make a faithful copy, test it and if still doen't work you may come back to me.

Comment: Okay I'm really sorry if I am wasting your time. You don't have to help me. And I actually honestly have been appreciating your help greatly as most of this doesn't make sense to me. I changed my `return really_new_split` to `return (set(new_split))` and my program at least ran this time. I'm supposed to end up with 58 words, but I ended up with about 500. If you continue to help me I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ok. Ii realise I asked you to indent the code after the `if __name__ == '__main__'::` but I meant just one level. So please of the three blocks leave the first where it is, dedent the second by one level and the last by two levels. and then try again.

Comment: YES! It worked! Thank you so much! It turns out it wasn't even my fault either. I did follow your directions for indenting but my text editor automatically formatted it in a weird way, so I thought that was correct. Everything is working perfectly except how can I make my last list sorted into alphabetical order? Thank you again so much!

Comment: use `sorted(unique_words)` I'll move our paper trail to chat. that may trigger an invitation to join me at chat. if it does just ignore it

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to work. I put it right before the for loop with unique words with the same indentation

Comment: You have to assign it to a new name or the same name if you like and then use that name in the last for loop. You were referring to the last for loop? So the simplest would be `unique_words = sorted(unique_words)`

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I keep forgetting this lol. I sincerely thank you so very much for your your time and your help. This truly has helped me so much I can't even begin to tell you. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for losing my temper.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Hi I'm not sure if you will see this but I posted another Python question and I could use your excellent help again. Thanks for your time should you decide to help me again, and also thank you again for helping me on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really not a lot missing: Step 1 put your code in a function so you can reuse it. You are doing the same thing (parsing a text file) several times so why not put the corresponding code in a reusable unit.

```
def get_words(filename):
    test_file = open(filename).read()
    lower_split = test_file.lower()
    new_split = re.split("[^a-z']+", lower_split)
    return set(new_split)
```

Step 2: Set up a loop to call your function. In this particular case we could use a list comprehension but maybe that's too much for a rookie. You'll come to that in good time:

```
bag = []
for filename in sys.argv[x:] # you'll have to experiment what to put
                             # for x it will be at least one because
                             # the first argument is the name of your
                             # program
    bag.append(get_words(filename))
```

Now you have all the words conveniently grouped by file. As I said, you can simply take the set difference. So if you want all the words that are *only* in the very last file:

```
 unique_words = bag[-1].copy()
 for other in bag[:-1]: loop over all the other files
     unique_words -= other

 for word in unique_words:
     print(word)
```

I didn't test it, so let me know whether it runs.

Comment: So I got one error that said
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tristan_ross_cs23_as01.py", line 14, in <module>
    unique_words = bag[-1].copy()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: That's strange, bag shouldn't contain any lists. We are only appending sets aren't we? What happens if you type `type(get_words(<filename>))` where filename is the name of one of your text files?

Comment: Sorry where do I type that statement within my program?

Comment: Ah, I can see the problem. Why don't you do the following: after the function, i.e. after the line with the return statement insert a line reading `if __name__ == '__main__':` and indent _all_ subsequent lines. Then if you call it as a script it will still run (or crash ...) but if you import it from a python shell it will just make the function available. if the name of your file is `tristan_ross.py` you type `import tristan_ross` and then `type(tristan_ross.get_words(<filename>))`

Comment: hmm I did what you said but I'm still getting the same error. I need to be able to run from a command line: `python my_file_name.py text_file_name.txt` so where would i put my import statement? in the file? I'm sorry if this is confusing I'm such a python noob haha

Comment: That wasn't meant to fix it but rather to find out why it doesn't work. You must have some kind of interactive python shell, no? Run it and import your file. What system are you on?

Comment: I'm on a windows machine but I'm using the SSH client PuTTy

Comment: Ok, try calling python without any arguments. this will get you to the interactive shell which is useful because it lets you test things and you get an immediate response. once there try what I suggested above.

Comment: Okay so I got to that point. But I think I might be doing something wrong: >>> type(tristan_ross_cs23_as01.get_words(<trump.txt>))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(tristan_ross_cs23_as01.get_words(<trump.txt>))
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You didn't write that code snippet did you? Anyway, try replacing the angular brackets with quotation marks.

Comment: there we go I got it to work                                                                             >>> type(tristan_ross_cs23_as01.get_words("trump.txt"))
<class 'list'>

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? Are you positive the last line in your function is `return set(new_split)` and if so what do you get if you type `set([1,2,3])` at the terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135899/discussion-between-paul-panzer-and-t-dog).

Answer (score 0):

Consider simplifying by using Set's difference operation, to 'subtract' the sets of words in your files.

```
import re

s1 = open('file1.txt', 'r').read()
s2 = open('file2.txt', 'r').read()
set(re.findall(r'\w+',s2.lower())) - set(re.findall(r'\w+',s1.lower()))
```

result:

```
{'really'}
```